# express to fall flipping uncontrollably from a high place

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Hi everyone is there a common way to express an uncontrolled fall, when the body goes flipping on it self before crashing. like in diving for example so that the question wouldn't be restricted starting 18 and above haha.

anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: ***Tumbling***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest, "He fell **head over heels** from the top of the stairs all the way down to the bottom".

**Head over heels:** Turning over completely in forward motion, as in a somersault (Google online).

Comment: @habibhassani And to satisfy the OP's requirement for something a little bit more colorful, may I suggest that he fell "arse-over-elbow", as in falling over in a dramatic fashion. Since my spellcheck objects to "arse", I think this slang expression is BE rather than AE.

Comment: It gets more colourful, 'arse over tit' is a common variant. (ps 'heals'?)

Comment: @Spagirl  Quite so! I missed your more colourful variant the first time round. How clever you are. Evidently you are not a booby!

Comment: I should add that the word "booby" crept back into the lexicon when my hero, Dr. Zachary Smith, the dastardly character in TV's Lost in Space, kept chiding his nemesis, the loquacious robot, with the put down, "You big booby!"

Comment: @PeterPoint You're up to your old tricks.

Comment: @RichardKayser Well, that's better than being a Tricky Dicky, isn't that so, Richard?

Comment: @PeterPoint Indeed. It is decidedly so. You've got me wondering about the hidden meaning of *PeterPoint*.

Comment: @RichardKayser ha-ha!

Comment: I missed a "ha", and the best one at that!

Comment: @PeterPoint We'd better stop ... for now. :-)

Comment: @PeterPoint Steady on, or I'll set Inspector Wilkie after you. (scroll down to 'wulkie') http://www.firstfoot.com/dictionary/w.html

Comment: @PeterPoint thanks but i feel like this describe the crashing moment while i need to point out the uncontrolled rotation movement on the air. sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: @habibhassani To indicate a rotating movement you might like to consider the word "spiral" or "spiraling". For example, the man fell off the top of the building and spiraled to the ground below.

Answer (score 1):

*Hurtle* [or *hurtling*] is a good word for this.

> [*hurtle*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=hurtling&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):
>   move or cause to move at a great speed, typically in a wildly
>   uncontrolled manner

Examples:

> "After he fell off the building, he *hurtled* toward the ground."
>
> "The damaged plane *hurtled* though the sky to its demise."

Comment: thank's but this kind of point out the speed while i need to indicate the rotating movement.

Comment: @habibhassani Okay. I think *hurtling* can include rotating (see *wildly uncontrolled manner*), I agree it doesn't have to. Thanks for the feedback.